Issue with WooCommerce widget filtering products by price range
I created a simple e-commerce website and uploaded around 100 products (all of them are Simple-Products). Initially, I had no problems, but after uploading about 60 products, I started receiving this error. Here is the error I am encountering:
Warning: Attempt to read property "min_price" on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\widgets\class-wc-widget-price-filter.php on line 91

Warning: Attempt to read property "max_price" on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\widgets\class-wc-widget-price-filter.php on line 92

This is the highlighted code line, suggested by the Warning:
//89      Find min and max price in current result set.
//90        $prices    = $this->get_filtered_price();
//91        $min_price = $prices->min_price;
//92        $max_price = $prices->max_price;

I checked some other answers for it and tried inserting the code from Filter products by price range using WooCommerce wc_get_products, although I do not know PHP well so I do not even know where to insert the code (I tried inserting it in functions.php in the WooCommerce Folder) but nothing worked. Some suggested updating WordPress or WooCommerce which I doubt will solve the problem unless anyone else suggests it here too. Others said that Variable-Products cause these, but I am sure that all of my products are Simple type.

This error comes from the widget that filter products by prices in here. Maybe the problem could be related to the way the products import has been done.
What you can try is (always make a database backup before):

first disable/remove temporarily the widget that filter product prices, if possible.
Then add the following code snippet in functions.php file of your child theme, that will re-save all your existing products (allowing data to be sync/refreshed in a correct way):

add_action('template_redirect', 'refresh_all_products');
function refresh_all_products() {
    // Loop through each product
    foreach ( wc_get_products(['limit' => -1]) as $product ) {
        $product->save(); // Sync and save data.
    }
}


Browse any page of your website (front-end).
Remove the code snippet,
Re-enable the widget that filter product prices (if needed).

This could solve the issue.
